# How can i select needed db for Pytest? I have 2 - one remote, one local. I need pytest to be started on local

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pytest, pytest-django

The default db is cloud one. And when pytest tries to create a temporary data it got permissions error. So i want to create a second database to be used with pytest. How can i select this database in pytest config?

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': config['database']['name'],
        'ENGINE': '...',
    },
    'tests_db': {
        "NAME": "tests_db",
        "ENGINE": 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

Comment: Easiest way is to add if statement in your setting file. if 'test' in sys.argv: And in that if statement declare your test database as default one

Comment: @TrueGopnik I did that, but i don't understand how to use this now :)

Comment: It should be picked automatically when you launch tests, does it still tries to connect to your cloud db?

Comment: @TrueGopnik actualy it doens't start at all :D
But i found solution and added it as Answer

Comment: @TrueGopnik I've tried your solution one more time and it works perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer having separate development and production settings. My production doesn't get muddied with an sqlite database for no reason and I can speed up tests with less security/other benefits.

```
settings/
│   base.py
│   heroku.py
│   test.py
```

```py
# settings/test.py

...

# Make password hashing faster
PASSWORD_HASHERS = ('django.contrib.auth.hashers.MD5PasswordHasher',)

# Use sqlite database
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': config['database']['name'],
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    }
}
```

Then change `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` to `"settings.test"` during tests. If you're using pytest with pytest-django, you can do this:

```
# setup.cfg
[tool:pytest]
addopts = --reuse-db --ds=settings.test
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.
For this kind of issue we have to create another db

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': config['database']['name'],
        'ENGINE': '...',
    },
    'tests_db': {
        'NAME': config['database']['name'],
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        }
}
```

And then in conftest.py we add

```
pytestmark = [pytest.mark.django_db(databases=["tests_db"])]
```